# [runway]: git repo link not working in path attribute

Tags: git, terraform, yaml

I am trying to source terraform module stored in github repo, but when I pass the git link of repo in the "path" attribute of modules section in runway.yml and execute runway plan, it returns error as follows:

```
$runway plan

return self.__git_ls_remote(self.__determine_git_ls_remote_ref())
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/runway/sources/git.py", line 77, in __git_ls_remote
ls_remote_output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['git', 'ls-remote', '', 'HEAD']' returned non-zero exit status 128.
```

I am able to clone the repo manually with git clone command on the host machine where runway is installed, and ssh key is also added to github repo.

`git ls-remote <repo_url> HEAD` is also returning output without any error on manual execution on the terminal. I am assuming it has to do something with ssh authentication.

runway.yml:

```
deployments:

name: test-deployment
modules:
path: git::git://<org>/terraform-google-bigquery.git
parameters:
dataset_id: "Testing-runway"
regions:
europe-west2
```

Runway version
2.6.8

Installation Type
pypi (pip, pipenv, poetry, etc)

OS / Environment
OS: Red hat Linux
terraform version: 1.5.2

Steps To Reproduce:

Add Git repo URL to path attribute in runway.yml and execute 'runway plan':

```
deployments:
name: test-deployment
modules:
path: git::git://<org>/terraform-google-bigquery.git
parameters:
dataset_id: "Testing-runway"
regions:
europe-west2
```

Expected Behavior:
runway plan should not return error

Comment: Have you tried using the HTTP clone URL in lieu of the GIT scheme? Would look like `git::https://<org>/terraform-google-bigquery.git`. If you need ssh then you probably need some configuration like `git config --global url."ssh://git@<org>".insteadOf https://<org>`.

Comment: I think I got the root cause: So protocol does not seem to be the problem here, but the URL format does. I tried removing all the hyphens("-") from the url and it detected the url. Not sure how runway handles the url parsing and how to make url with "-" work.

Comment: Your two YAML blocks appear to not have any indentation. Are they really like that on your machine?

Comment: indentation is fine and didn't cause any problems, it probably got changed while pasting blocks here

Answer (score 0):

github.com does not accept the `git://` protocol, mostly because that protocol doesn't have any means of authentication. You need to use either HTTPS or SSH.